# Where should data validation be done?

Tags: java, web-services, validation, configuration

I have a java Web service, where I get data from configuration file and different web service.

For this I have these Classes:

- Main - my main class with some logic, where I call ConfigurationManager and WebServiceClient classes
- ConfigurationManager - to read configurations from file
- WebServiceClient - calling First web service

I should validate data retrieved either from Configuration file or different Web service.

Should I do this validation in ConfigurationManager of WebServiceClient 
classes or in Main class?

Where should I do this data validation?

Comment: Earlier the validation can be performed, it should be. 'Fail fast' be the strategy I think

Comment: This I understand but, if we think from the point of single responsibility principle is ConfigurationManager class the place where validation  should be done.

Comment: "Never trust the client" is an ancient software engineering proverb.